# Restrict buying of only the related product

Tags: product, product-relations, restriction

I'm using Magento 2.3. I need to have the feature, where I've a two products A & B.

Now, a customer can buy product A and can buy product B only with product A. Product B cannot be sold separately.

Thus, if the customer adds product A and B, and deletes product A from the cart, then product B must also get deleted. However, if product B is only deleted, then product A must still remain in the cart.

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered adding a configuration to product A "Include product B". This way you can buy product A separated or together with product B. The downside of this is that you will not have a separated stock, configurations, description,... for product B?

Comment: @ArnoVandeCappelle Yes. However, since Product B is a separate SKU, with its own independent stock, we can't have that.